# Node PostgreSQL timeout a query by the client

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, postgresql, timeout

I'm using Node package `pg` for postgres ([here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)):

```
npm i pg

var pg = require('pg');
```

I'm querying a large cluster which is not owned by me, and under certain conditions may fail. Failure may be bad response which is easy to handle or endless query.
Please note I can not introduce changes [config or otherwise] on the DB side.

Is there any way to set a timeout for query time?
I'd like my client to give up after a set time, and return timeout error.

Couldn't find anything as such in the docs.

Thanks from ahead!

Comment: Only via `cancel` command, it seems, according to the author: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/518

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is using an init query, to set query timeout for the session.

```
    SET statement_timeout TO 15000; # x milliseconds or 0 (turns off limitation)
```

This takes an argument of the timeout in ms, and is applied for the session.
Afterwards, when a query takes longer than the value specified, you will receive an error from the server. Note this is *on user's request*:

```
    ERROR:  Query (150) cancelled on user's request
```

Also note this actually cancels the query on the server side, reducing load.

Answer (score 14):

You can setup [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) in the client:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
  statement_timeout: 10000
})
```

or in the pool:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
  statement_timeout: 10000
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while and I no longer use Node.js, but that's great for future Googlers. :)